# How to check the type of a parameter in Haxe

Tags: arrays, haxe

I'm converting a JavaScript library to Haxe.
It seems Haxe is very similar to JS, but in working I got a problem for function overwriting.

For example, in the following function `param` can be an an integer or an array.

JavaScript:

```
function testFn(param) {
    if (param.constructor.name == 'Array') {
        console.log('param is Array');
        // to do something for Array value
    } else if (typeof param === 'number') {
        console.log('param is Integer');
        // to do something for Integer value
    } else {
        console.log('unknown type');
    }
}
```

Haxe:

```
function testFn(param: Dynamic) {
    if (Type.typeof(param) == 'Array') { // need the checking here
        trace('param is Array');
        // to do something for Array value
    } else if (Type.typeof(param) == TInt) {
        trace('param is Integer');
        // to do something for Integer value
    } else {
        console.log('unknown type');
    }
}
```

Of course Haxe supports `Type.typeof()` but there isn't any `ValueType` for `Array`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Haxe, you'd usually use the `is` operator for this instead of `Type.typeof()`. Behind the scenes, the operator uses [`Std.isOfType()`](https://api.haxe.org/Std.html#isOfType).

```
if (param is Array) {
    trace('param is Array');
} else if (param is Int) {
    trace('param is Integer');
} else {
    trace('unknown type');
}
```

It's possible to use `Type.typeof()` as well, but less common - you can use [pattern matching](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-enums.html) for this purpose. Arrays are of [`ValueType.TClass`](https://api.haxe.org/ValueType.html?#TClass), which has a `c:Class<Dynamic>` parameter:

```
switch (Type.typeof(param)) {
    case TClass(Array):
        trace("param is Array");
    case TInt:
        trace("param is Int");
    case _:
        trace("unknown type");
}
```